# how to complete the amazon-lex chatbot conversation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, chatbot

i am trying to create a Amazon LEX - chat bot v2 for start and stop ec2 instance .

but i am facing a error :

i am mentioning all the prompts in the  lex as a chat conversation :

### The conversation flow is shown below :

my conversion flow is :

Initial request - sample utterance  = I want to start a server {instance}
Acknowledge intent - initial response = sure , i can do that for u
Prompt for more information - slot  = may i know which instance u want to start ?
Capture information - slot value = qa
Confirm intent - confirmation prompt = can i confirm your request ?
Fulfilment was completed successfully - success response = your request is successful
Fulfilment failed to complete - failure response = something went wrong
Send final response - closing response = Thank you !!!!!!

and i am invoking my lambda function in fulfilment stage

### And my lambda function is

```
import boto3
import logging
import os
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.environ['TZ'] = 'Asia/Kolkata'
    time.tzset()
    logger.debug('Received event: %s', event)
    return dispatch(event)

def dispatch(intent_request):
    intent_name = intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['name']
    
    if intent_name == 'stopinstance':
        return stop_ec2(intent_request)
    elif intent_name == 'start-Server':
        return start_ec2(intent_request)
         
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')

def stop_ec2(intent_request):
    output_session_attributes = {}
    slots = intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['slots']
    instance_value = slots['instance']['value']['interpretedValue']
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = ec2.describe_instances()
    
    insId = []
    instance_found = False
    
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            for tag in instance.get("Tags", []):
                if tag["Value"] == instance_value:
                    insId.append(instance["InstanceId"])
                    instance_found = True
                    break
            if instance_found:
                break
    
    if instance_found:
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=insId)
        message = {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Stopping instance {} successfully'.format(instance_value)
        }
        return close(output_session_attributes, 'Fulfilled', message)
    else:
        message = {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Instance {} not found.'.format(instance_value)
        }
        return close(output_session_attributes, 'Fulfilled', message)


def start_ec2(intent_request):
    output_session_attributes = {}
    slots = intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['slots']
    long_instance_value = slots['instance']['value']
    instance_value = long_instance_value['originalValue']
    region_name = 'us-east-1'  # Set your desired region
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_name)
    response = ec2.describe_instances()
    
    insId = []
    instance_found = False
    
    for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            for tag in instance.get("Tags", []):
                if tag["Value"] == instance_value:
                    insId.append(instance["InstanceId"])
                    instance_found = True
                    break
            if instance_found:
                break
    
    if instance_found:
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=insId)
        message = {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Starting instance {} successfully'.format(instance_value)
        }
    else:
        message = {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Instance {} not found.'.format(instance_value)
        }
    return close(output_session_attributes, 'Fulfilled', message)

def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
    }
    return response
```

---

**I have given all the permission to lambda ( to access ec2 ) and for lex ( to communicate with lambda )**

and i am able to start and stop the ec2.

but my conversation is incomplete in the bot UI .

below image are of test bot ui

[bot interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WA18.png)
[bot interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC5OK.png)

**the error u have seen in the image is :**
Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Cannot construct instance of `IntentResponse`, problem: The validated object is null at [Source: (String)"{"sessionAttributes": {}, "dialogAction": {"type": "Close", "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled", "message": {"contentType": "PlainText", "content": "Starting instance qa successfully"}}}"; line: 1, column: 182]

**i am able to start and stop and ec2**

---

**but i want the conversation to be completed with**

### Fulfilment was completed successfully - success response = your request is successful
Fulfilment failed to complete - failure response = something went wrong
Send final response - closing response = Thank you !!!!!!

but it is not promting

---

please help me out ....

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you're using the Lex V1 response format as opposed to V2 which is why you're getting the error.

Have a look at the expected output format here:- [AWS Lex V2 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda-response-format.html)

Here's a sample of how your `close` method should look:-

```
def close(intent_request, session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    intent_request['sessionState']['intent']['state'] = fulfillment_state
    return {
        'sessionState': {
            'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
            'dialogAction': {
                'type': 'Close'
            },
            'intent': intent_request['sessionState']['intent']
        },
        'messages': [message],
        'sessionId': intent_request['sessionId'],
        'requestAttributes': intent_request['requestAttributes'] if 'requestAttributes' in intent_request else None
    }
```